# jQuery validation engine, set minsize but allow empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have using jQuery validation engine,

I try to let empty text field, but validate while the field not empty

my code is like this

```
<input name="t_city" type="text" id="t_city" placeholder="CITY" class="validate[minSize[6]]">
```

and my javascript is like this

```
$("form").validationEngine({
        onValidationComplete:function(form, status){
            var city = $("input#t_city").val();

            if(status == true){ alert(city); }
        }
    }
}
```

How to validate to allow if the input field is empty.?

Answer (score 2):

change `class="validate[minSize[6]]"` to `class="validate[optional,minSize[6]]"`

**HTML:**

```
<input name="t_city" type="text" id="t_city" placeholder="CITY" class="validate[optional,minSize[6]]">
```

Comment: nothing error, it just showing popup notification Minimum 6 characters allowed

Comment: are you included  `optional` in class? that class should be `validate[optional,minSize[6]]`

Comment: I've already change the class as you wish, but still not worked.

Comment: okay... http://jsfiddle.net/usT6R/8/ but it seems no error, I dont understand why my code not appearing like that

Comment: the problem is, I've edit the jquery.validationEngine-en.js, thats why  the optional css is not worked